Why Does SwiftUI Matched Geometry Transition of Text Have Asymmetrical Behavior?
In this SwiftUI code, why does the matched geometry effect have a weird asymmetry (there is a slight left/right and up/down wavering -- the Text does not simply animate in a "straight line" from it source and target configuration.)
import SwiftUI

struct MatchedGeometryExample: View {
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            HStack{
                Text("Example Text")
                    .font(isExpanded ? .largeTitle : .body)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "exampleText", in: animationNamespace)
                    .padding()
                
                    .background(.pink)
            }

            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MatchedGeometryExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MatchedGeometryExample()
    }
}


Using matchedGeometryEffect here doesn't make sense - you only used it on one view. Which other view do you want the Text's geometry to match?

It's just something i want to know the answer to -- a minimal/non realistic example, but a small piece of a larger problem.

In any case, adding drawingGroup() fixed the issue for me. This probably has something to do with how font sizes are animated compared to the frame of the view, though I don't know about the details. Animating scaleEffect for example, doesn't have this problem.
